# jquery "$.when" function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

I am attempting to use the jquery `$.when()` function to prevent certain functions from being fired until the ajax completes. I have the below function but the deferred functions are still firing at the same time as the ajax call.

code:

```
 $.when(cdeckDataStore("param1","param2","param3")).done([function1("param1"),function2("param1")]);


function cdeckDataStore(action,step,checked) {
   return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      url: "url/to/api",
      data: {"action":action,"step":step,"data": checked},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
      }
   });

}
```

according to the docs `function1` and `function2` should wait until the ajax returns to fire.

am I missing something?

Comment: are you certain the error handler is not getting called?

Comment: I am seeing "success" in the console.

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974649/jquery-when-then-also-when-done-not-waiting - You dont need to pass success/error. $.ajax() is a promise. But success/error are not promises.

Comment: You are correct, a failure would still invoke the promise. I got away with ignoring jquery for years until I used angular, which uses jquery under the hood.

Comment: You're calling the functions in the array, and returning whatever those two functions return to the array passed to done. What you need is an anonymous function that wraps the two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, according to docs the references passed to `.done()` will be invoked after `$.when()` is done.

Whereas you're invoking your functions in place `function1("param1")`

You could pass a reference to a function using something like:

```
function1.bind(this, 'param1')
```

Comment: thank you, but what about this. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/#deferred-done-doneCallbacks-doneCallbacks "A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved." I am passing an array of functions.

Comment: @arrowill12: nope, you're passing an array of what functions return. Scroll to examples and compare `done( [ fn1, fn2 ], fn3, [ fn2, fn1 ] )` to your code. You see - they only pass function names (references), but don't call them like `fn1()`