# Delay jquery ui dialog close until after callback is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am calling up a confirm box using jQuery UI Dialog like so:

```
function tps_show_confirm(cTitle, cContent, noClose = true, dwidth = 300, callback=null) {
    if (noClose == true) {
        var dClass = 'no-close';
    } else {
        var dClass = '';
    }
    var confirmDiv = '<div class="tps-confirm-modal">'+cContent+'</div>';
    var maxHeight = window.innerHeight * .80;
    $( confirmDiv ).dialog({
        title: cTitle,
        dialogClass: dClass,
        modal: true,
        width: dwidth,
        maxHeight: maxHeight,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            $('body').css({ overflow: 'hidden' })
        },
        beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
            $('body').css({ overflow: 'inherit' })
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
                    callback(); 
                }
                $( this ).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to delay the `.dialog('close')` action when the OK button is clicked until the callback() function is finished. I've tried various combinations of .done() an/or .finish() and .when() but I don't quite understand those and they don't seem to be for this case.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully [**jquery.when**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) will be useful

```
  Ok: function() {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
                    $.when(callback()).then(function() {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                 }.bind(this));
                }else{
                   $( this ).dialog('close');
                }

            }
```

This snippet can be useful. I am passing a callback back function.Inside a callback function there is an asynchronous call.Now when you will click on `ok` button the callback function will start executing but the dialog will be closed only when there is a response from async operation

```js
function tps_show_confirm(callback = null) {
  var confirmDiv = '<div class="tps-confirm-modal">Hello Test</div>';
  var maxHeight = window.innerHeight * .80;
  $(confirmDiv).dialog({
    title: 'test',
    dialogClass: 'dClass',
    modal: true,
    width: 300,
    maxHeight: 300,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $('body').css({
        overflow: 'hidden'
      })
    },
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      $('body').css({
        overflow: 'inherit'
      })
    },
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          $.when(callback()).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }.bind(this));
        } else {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }

      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
}

function test() {
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  return $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/1',
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {
    return data;
  });

}
tps_show_confirm(test)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising indeed. But, the modal is still closing immediately on clicking OK before the callback is finished for some reason...

Comment: How are you checking if the callback have finished it's execution?

Comment: Isn't $.when supposed to detect when the callback is finished in this case?

Comment: I think my problem is related to this, since the callback function uses ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974649/jquery-when-then-also-when-done-not-waiting. Taking a look now...

Comment: Thank you for the expanded explanation. I think I'm getting close between your post and the one I linked. I'll return once I get it sussed out.